# Android AppWidgetProvider listen to the callback from service

Tags: android, appwidgetprovider

I'm trying to catch callback in my widget provider from any services with broadcast.
But this doesn't work.

This is my widget provider

```
public class MyProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    final String LOG_TAG = "States";
    public final static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "action";
    BroadcastReceiver br;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "receive intent"); // No fire here!!

            }
        };
        IntentFilter intFilt = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        context.registerReceiver(br, intFilt);
    }
}
```

This is my remoteViewsFactory from where I wanna catch callbacks.

```
public class MyFactory implements RemoteViewsFactory {

    Context context;
    int widgetID;
    final String LIST_READY = "list_ready";
    public final static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "action";

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(LIST_READY, 1);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Maybe it's wrong way? How to organize broadcasting between widget and factory better?

Answer (score 0):

> This is my widget provider

This should be crashing, as an `AppWidgetProvider` is a `BroadcastReceiver`, and you cannot call `registerReceiver()` on the `Context` supplied to `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Regardless, once `onUpdate()` returns, your `AppWidgetProvider` instance is gone, along with its registered receiver. If your `AppWidgetProvider` lives for more than a millisecond, you're doing it wrong.

> I'm trying to catch callback in my widget provider from any services with broadcast

I am not quite certain what you are trying to accomplish. Bear in mind that a service, or anything else, can update an app widget directly, via `AppWidgetManager`. If you have common code for updating the app widget contents, put that in a `static` method or utility class, and use it from both the `AppWidgetProvider` and from the service (or whatever else needs to update the app widget).